# SignUp form: inserting data into MySQL using Android 4.0

Tags: android, mysql, authentication, http-post

Currently I'm developing a registration form for new user in Android (native app.) and by using .php file. By runnig the code I'm getting following error: "Unfortunately, application has stopped". I tried to change code in many ways to solve it, but without any result. Here is the php code:

```
<?php 
$dbcnx = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
$db = "dbname";
mysql_select_db($db, $dbcnx);
$user_id=$_POST['user'];
$passwd=$_POST['passwd'];
$query = 'INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (NULL, \''.$user_id.'\', \''.$passwd.'\')';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("<b>Query failed:</b> " . mysql_error());

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($dbcnx);
?>
```

And .java file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Register extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    Button Insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    Insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                EditText Text1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_id);
                EditText Text2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwd);                 

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", ""+Text1.getText().toString()+""));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passwd", ""+Text2.getText().toString()+""));

                Log.e(""+Text1.getText().toString(),"0");
                Log.e(""+Text2.getText().toString(),"0");
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/jku/user_reg.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }

        }
    });

}   

}
```

I fixated on my mistakes, so I'm beginner in android and any suggestions would be helpful.

I've checked LogCat but nothing understand. So here is the log story:

```
01-04 21:37:13.275: D/gralloc_goldfish(552): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-04 21:37:13.345: W/TextLayoutCache(552): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
01-04 21:37:47.385: D/AndroidRuntime(552): Shutting down VM
01-04 21:37:47.385: W/dalvikvm(552): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jku.project.kusss/jku.project.kusss.Register}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at jku.project.kusss.Register.onCreate(Register.java:27)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
01-04 21:37:47.476: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Use logcat do get mor information on the error and add a stacktrace please.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace of the error? You can get this output from eclipse or "adb logcat". Also, for safety reasons, you should look into PDO when doing SQL interactions with PHP. http://ca3.php.net/pdo It makes your life easier to write safer SQL interactions.

Comment: I've added above the LogCat. By the way code procedure is right? Without mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is in the error stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id
attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Since you didn't show all of your code, lets assume you're using a ListActivity or a ListFragment or whatever.  To use that, the view must have a ListView child with an ID of `android.R.id.list`.

Read the paragraph under 'Screen Layout' in [this d.android.com link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

Comment: **Chris**, thank you for your suggestion. I just changed in .java ListActivity to Activity and it runs without errors. But on clicking Register button nothing happening :( yet, i.e. no saving data into mysql. Anybody can help?

Comment: Anybody can check please this code procedure? It's not working :(